# Build Android app to run in JRE

Tags: android, cross-platform, java

I have seen questions and topics in google referencing running JRE apps in the android environment, but I am actually thinking about the reverse.

I understand Android runs on a different runtime engine than the standard JRE.

Is it possible to build an app to run on android, but also build and run the same app in the JRE on a desktop?

I assume there would be restrictions on API usage, I was just thinking about the possibility to distribute a simple app that could be useful on both the device and the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bigger problem here is going to be accessing the Android API and environment on your desktop. Do you have a plan for that?

If you have the Android environment running on your desktop then there shouldn't be any problem running your app there.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893991/cross-platform-java-android-and-desktop) offers an alternative suggestion.

**Short answer:** your desktop and Android app can share a large portion of code, but you aren't going to be able to run Android-specific code on the desktop.

Comment: right, I guess I assumed there would be restrictions on API usage, I was just thinking about the possibility to distribute an app that could be useful on both the device and the desktop.

Comment: I don't think the app itself (as a bundle or .apk) will run on both, but certainly the development can share a good deal of code.